# Unexpected behavior on QWidget while the event filtering

Tags: qt, qwidget, qpushbutton, eventfilter

Just i've tested the following codes on QPushButton and on QWidget and i've encountered with different behaviors. But why?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) 
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->widget->setStyleSheet("background:blue;");
    ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("background:blue;");
    ui->widget->installEventFilter(this);
    ui->pushButton->installEventFilter(this);

        ...
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event)
{
    if (watched==ui->pushButton && event->type()==QEvent::Paint)
    {
        // Do nothing
        return true;
    }
    else if (watched==ui->widget && event->type()==QEvent::Paint)
    {
        // Do nothing
        return true;
    }
    else
        return QMainWindow::eventFilter(watched, event);
}
```

Then, the pushButton has disappeared as normally, because i've masked its paintEvent with eventFilter. But the widget has painted to blue. Why widget hasn't disappeared.

Comment: But the QPushButton is derived from QWidget and it's work, right?

Comment: You might want to check the value of the `autoFillBackground` property for both the `QWidget` and the `QPushButton`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem with changing `QEvent::Paint` with `QEvent::Polish`.

[To who wanted the detailed description](https://forum.qt.io/topic/68864/unexpected-behavior-on-qwidget-while-the-event-filtering)

Thanks everybody.